# Hawaiian palm tree. Scale or something else?

Tags: trees, palm, scale

I have an indoor palm tree. I noticed some slightly sticky clear sap at the base of the leaves, and some tiny grey or brown specs bunched up at the same location that looks like a scale infestation. I am attaching a photo.  Any clues on what this might be?  Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

first of all, that's not a palm, that's a Plumeria i believe. They were introduced to Hawaii. All parts of the plumeria are considered toxic and the sap itself has a propensity to cause rash in sensitive skin.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.